# What is single-precision 32-bit IEEE 754 floating point?

Tags: java, floating-point

so, I'm quite new to the programming world. Java piqued my interest and I am now currently taking some online courses.

tutorialspoint.com states that float is "single precision 32bit IEEE 754 floating point" and couldn't quite make anything from it.

I would be extremely grateful for the help.

Comment: IEEE 754 defines the standard for representing floating point numbers. 24 (23 + 1) bits in the mantissa and 8 bits in the exponent.

Comment: Did you try [googling](https://www.google.co.uk/#q=what+is+single-precision+32-bit+IEEE+754+floating+point?) for your exact title? If so, I'd suggest asking follow-on questions about whichever bits (if any) still don't make sense. As it stands, the question is too broad for a good answer here.

Comment: There are so many good explanations on the web, no one here but elsewhere, so easily found.

Comment: couldn't quite find it. thanks a lot everyone.

Comment: Start with https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html. Easier versions exist if you search.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In same 32 bits you can use for example 20 bits for digits and 12 for exponent, or 28 bits for digits and 4 for exponent. IEEE754 is standard of this distribution - 11+5, 24+8, 53+11, 113+15, 237+19

Ie "32bit IEEE 754" mean that 24 of 32 bits is digits and 8 bits is exponent

Comment: Don't forget the sign bit!

Comment: It means a lot more than just the distribution of the bits. It provides an extensive definition of the semantics.